# Messages sent to gmail from custom domain going to spam

Tags: email, filter, header, gmail, spam

I know this isnt kind of perfect type of message to post here, but I will give it a try:

When I send an email from my domain to gmail, it automatically goes to spam. On customer support, they told me that my domain isnt on any kind of blacklist.

Here are the headers:

http://pastebin.com/QVYrDQbz

Answer (score 2):

**Ask gmail recipients** to move messages from `[GMAIL]/Junk` folder to `Inbox` folder (IMAP terminology) or mark it as "not spam" via web interface.

As long as **recipients** do not tell gmail its "classification as (possible) spam" had been wrong gmail assumes it has been right.

---

- It may help to publish spf record for domain of email sender especially when sending host is in another domain
- DKIM signing of outgoing messages may help too

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en#authentication